# Arduino RS485 do I need MAX485?

Tags: arduino-uno, rs485, modbus, convert

I'm trying to connect sesnor that use RS485 (I'm almost sure that's modbus). The sensor has RX/TX and +/- wires. Do I still need a component between the RX/TX pin from the Arduino UNO and the sensor itself? All the libraries I reviewed have an additional control pin. Or do I need, for example, a MAX485? Is it possible to simply connect RX of sensor to RX of UNO, TX of sensor to TX of UNO and + to 5V of UNO, and - to - ?

Comment: similar question https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53287/dmx-on-the-arduino-without-additional-driver-chip

Comment: @Juraj So I need MAX485